# Different log4j settings when running with Maven than when running from Eclipse

Tags: maven, junit, log4j, logback

I'd like my console to be as quiet as possible when I run my tests with `mvn test`, unless something goes wrong. Then again, when I'm writing tests in Eclipse (in other words, when I run single junit tests inside Eclipse), it's ok for them to be pretty verbose.

So I would need a way to have different log4j/logback settings when running all my tests with surefire than when I run them one by one in Eclipse. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can configure surefire to use a different logger settings file. That will be ignored by Eclipse.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <argLine>-Dlogback.configuration=[wherever]</argLine>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```